# Use a specific typo3 page for default meta tags

Tags: typo3

Like the title says, I'd like to manage default meta tags with a specific typo3 page.
I figured out the text-fields like

```
  og:description {
    data = DB:pages:49:og_description
    override {
      required = 1
      data = field:og_description
    }
  }
```

But it won't work with

```
og:image {
    cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
    cObject {
        file {
            import.data = DB:pages:49:og_image
            treatIdAsReference = 1
            import.listNum = 0
        }
    }
}
```

What am I missing?
Thanks

EDIT:
With a little more research and try and error (There is no fileId in page) i got his working

```
og:image {
        attribute = property
        stdWrap.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
        stdWrap.cObject {
            file {
                import.data = DB:pages:156:og_image
                import.listNum = 0
            }
            begin = 0
            maxItems = 1
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj {
                stdWrap.typolink {
                    parameter.stdWrap {
                        cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
                        cObject {
                            file {
                                crop.data = file:current:crop
                                cropVariant = facebook_variant1
                                import.data = file:current:uid
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    returnLast = url
                    forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                }
                required = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Its alle fine, BUT: This won't add the URL to the Image. (should be exact the Same)

```
twitter:image {
        attribute = property
        stdWrap.cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
        stdWrap.cObject {
            file {
                import.data = DB:pages:156:twitter_image
                import.listNum = 0
            }
            begin = 0
            maxItems = 1
            renderObj = TEXT
            renderObj {
                stdWrap.typolink {
                    parameter.stdWrap {
                        cObject = IMG_RESOURCE
                        cObject {
                            file {
                                crop.data = file:current:crop
                                cropVariant = facebook_variant1
                                import.data = file:current:uid
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    returnLast = url
                    forceAbsoluteUrl = 1
                }
                required = 1
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your snippet works fine for me in a TYPO3 v10.4.1.

Comment: Thats Strange, for me in pages og_image was 1. So the Image was allways wrong. If i change 1 to the right Id from sys_file, it works fine.

Comment: In the database, pages.og_image *is* 1. But that's the count of relations between the page and sys_file/sys_filereference-records. It's *not* the uid of the file itself.

Both snippets should be processed in the same way. If not, the problem is somewhere else. Maybe a cache issue?